# If post does not exist, do something

Tags: posts, get-posts, 404-error

Is this possible? If so, how?

I am linking to a non-existing post/page where I get a `404 error`. I want to have it to get the url of the `non-existing post` and make it a link on my 404 page, but I don't want it to throw an error (so no 404 page, just a simple page). When I click this, I want it to go to the page where I can add posts (from the front end with a plugin called `User Submitted Posts`). Is this possible?

BTW: showing related posts by getting the link would be nice too. But I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in your template you create a `404.php` **all not-found requests will be handled by this template file**, and there you can put whatever you want.

Just as example, in the `404.php` file is possible to use something like (it's just a draft):

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<h3>
<?php
$slug = get_query_var('name');
if ( $slug ) {
    $name = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $slug));
    printf( __('Searching for post &quot;%s&quot;?') . ' ', $name );
    _e('It does not exists, maybe you can create it.');
} else {
    $name = '';
    _e('Content you required not exists, maybe you can create it.');
}
?>
<h3>
<div id="user-submitted-posts-wrapper" data-name="<?php echo $name; ?>">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[user-submitted-posts]'); ?>
</div>

<script>
jQuery().ready(function($) {
   var name = $('#user-submitted-posts-wrapper').data('name');
   if ( name != '') $('.usp-title input').eq(0).value(name);
});
</script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The plugin do **not** support precompiling post title, but you can fill it with jquery.
I inserted the script echoing it directly in the footer for answer semplicity, but is much better register and enqueue it using [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [wp_equeue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). You have also ensure that jquery is included in the page, and if you use `wp_register_script` you can put jquery in the script dependencies.

### Advanced Task

If you want to differentiate some 404 from others you can hook the `template_include` filter.
E.g. if you want to show a different 404 if the required post type is 'product', you can use:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'change_404_template');

function change_404_template($template) {
  if ( is_404() && ( get_query_var('post_type') == 'product' ) ) {
      return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/my-custom-template-for-not-found.php' ;
  }
  return $template;
}
```

Different approach is make a full redirect on 404. This is less performant, because 2 requests are sended to server (one that cause 404 and the second is the redirect) , but in some cases this method can be useful. If you want to follow this way hooks on `template_redirect` action:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_404');

function redirect_404() {
  if ( is_404() && ( get_query_var('post_type') == 'product') ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() ); // I redirect to home, you can redirect wherever you want
    exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. G.M. , but I need something more generic. If the post does not exist, it must show me no error actually (so no 404), but a page that has a link to 'make this post' and getting the post name....

Comment: And what's stopping you to insert `<?php do_shortcode('[user-submitted-posts]'); ?>` in the `404.php` file?

Comment: Hmm, interesting one... So writing in a 404 page... Did not think about that... The problem might be that people still have to write the postname that they did not found... Is there a way to catch the postname and put that in an input field in this one? If there is, than this problem is solved.

Comment: In WP url there isn't post title, but **slug**. WP obtain slug from title using func `sanitize_title` that is not *full* reversible. In my code, if you see, there is `$slug = get_query_var('name')` that try to cacht the requested post name and convert it to a more readable title: `$name = ucwords(str_replace('-',' ',$slug))` so if someone click the link `http://yousite.com/2013/07/my-test-post/` ('my-test-post' is the slug) and this post not exists 404.php is called and `$name` var will be **"My Post Slug"** and you can use it as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that's clear. Anyhow, I tried  your first code and set it on `404.php`, but I got an error  `unexpected ','`

Comment: There was another type, I corrected it. I am now seeing this `Searching for post "Asfasfafs"? It does not exists, maybe you can create it.`, which is great, but the `user submitted posts` area does not come along? So I only see this text and nothing else...

Comment: Works great man! Last question: is there a way to put the searched post title into a input field in this shortcode? So the input field in the plugin?

Comment: The plugin do no support title pre-filling but you can do it via javascript. **See my last edit**. If the code in the aswer works for you I think you have to accept it...

Comment: Thanks brother, that's a nice pointer. I will accept it, of course.